# Automatically hide border if fill color is "none" in TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, automation

I have a defined command as shown in the MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\shapes[3]
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[fill=#2] (0,2.5) circle (0.5);
\draw[fill=#3] (3,2) ellipse (1 and 0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\shapes{yellow}{green!50}{red!50}

\end{document}
```

Sometimes I don't want to color a particular shape in, which is when I set the fill color to `none`, like so: `\shapes{yellow}{none}{none}`.

However, when I do this, I don't want the border to remain (in other words, I want the shape to disappear completely if I specify the color as `none` – I don't want the border to remain.

Is there a good way to way to automatically make the border color none (or perhaps make the `\draw` command a `\fill` command, *if* the fill color is none (which would get rid of the border)?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Borders are not visible as expected. I wonder if `\newcommand\shapes[3]
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\fill[fill=#2] (0,2.5) circle (0.5);
\fill[fill=#3] (3,2) ellipse (1 and 0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}}` doesn't gives what you like to have?

Comment: @Zarko Sorry, I don't understand; isn't that code snippet exactly what's in my MWE? Sorry if I wasn't clear – I wanted no borders if the fill was none, and borders otherwise. TeXnician showed me how to do it using `ifthen` conditionals (which I guess is the best way to do it, it seems)

Comment: than please correct question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `draw` key.

[image: borders]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\shapes[3]
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[draw=#1,fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[draw=#2,fill=#2] (0,2.5) circle (0.5);
\draw[draw=#3,fill=#3] (3,2) ellipse (1 and 0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\shapes{yellow}{green!50}{red!50}
\shapes{yellow}{none}{none}

\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* This version keeps the border.

[image: with border]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand\shapes[3]
{\begin{tikzpicture}
\ifthenelse{\equal{none}{#1}}{\def\mycol{#1}}{\def\mycol{black}}
\draw[draw=\mycol,fill=#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\ifthenelse{\equal{none}{#2}}{\def\mycol{#2}}{\def\mycol{black}}
\draw[draw=\mycol,fill=#2] (0,2.5) circle (0.5);
\ifthenelse{\equal{none}{#3}}{\def\mycol{#3}}{\def\mycol{black}}
\draw[draw=\mycol,fill=#3] (3,2) ellipse (1 and 0.75);
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\shapes{yellow}{green!50}{red!50}
\shapes{yellow}{none}{none}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want there to be a border if there is a fill color, but none if I specify `none` as the fill color!

Comment: @SkeletonBow See the update

Comment: I tried updating but it told me I had the latest version of LaTeX

Comment: @SkeletonBow If someone writes "See the update" on this sites he/she means the edited post ;)